# What exactly is a "non-archival venue" and "workshop with proceedings"?

Tags: publications, citations

Questions:

1. What do people exactly mean when they say "non-archival venues" although the venue might have "publications"?
2. What is the exact difference between "workshop with proceedings" and one without it? Is there a way to determine this without having to contact organizers?

**Note 1**: I perfectly understand the *consequence* of being archival or having proceedings however what I want understand the *meaning* of these terms. For example, if workshop puts out pdfs of accepted papers on its website, is it considered proceedings? Is your paper now "archived"? Or is it "published" only if it has DOI? If you submitted short paper and it was assigned DOI but they never put out online copy of your paper anywhere then is it considered "published"? What exactly does "archiving" mean in academic context and how exactly is it supposed to be done by the organizers?

**Note 2**: I understand there might not be one well established standards but I would like to know common understanding in the community. For example, Venue1 says you are allowed to publish elsewhere but they also go ahead and assign DOIs anyway. Venue2 says they don't accept papers published elsewhere. So now what? if your paper in Venue1 really "published"?

Answer (score 10):

> 1. What do people exactly mean when they say "non-archival venues" although the venue might have "publications"?

Usually a conference/workshop is made "non-archival" so that the research presented at the venue can be published somewhere else (either before or after the event), i.e. the venue does not require exclusivity. An author can present their work to the conference/workshop specialized community, while at the same time keep the option to publish it in another reputable venue (for instance a journal). It seems common that the venue would let the authors choose whether they want their paper to be published in the proceedings or not, in this case the proceedings are made of the papers whose authors opted in. Example: https://sites.google.com/view/acl19studentresearchworkshop/call-for-paper.

> 2. What is the exact difference between "workshop with proceedings" and one without it? Is there a way to determine this without having to contact organizers?

The difference is literally that in one case the papers are published in the proceedings of the workshop, in the other they are not. In my experience workshops without proceedings do not require submission of a full paper, only a one page abstract for instance. There are also some conferences/workshop which don't have proceedings, but the abstracts presented can be selected for publication later as a full paper in a journal. In general this kind of information should be provided in the call for papers, but if it's not then the only way to know is to contact the organizers.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the *consequence* of not being archival or proceedings however what I want understand the *meaning* of what is considered *archive* and *proceedings*. For example, if workshop puts out pdfs of accepted papers on its website, is it considered proceedings? Or is it "published" only if it has DOI? If you submitted short paper, it was assigned DOI then is it considered "published"? What exactly does "archiving" mean in this context and how exactly is it done by organizers?

Comment: I don't know the specific meaning of archiving in this context, I suspect that there's no or little difference with proceedings. What is sure is that if a pdf paper is made available online, then it is published (in the same way as anything else: a blog post or a tweet is published as soon as it's online). A DOI is a convenience to identify something which was published, but it's not at all a requirement. The question is more about what a journal/conference accepts as original research: usually this includes content which was previously published as pre-print or abstract, but not always